# random.shuffle() возвращает None

Tags: python, python-3.x, случайные-числа, shuffle

есть код:

```
import random

mylist = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
print(random.shuffle(mylist))
```

код возвращает None и я не могу понять почему

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что функция `random.shuffle()` ничего не возвращает, она **изменяет** исходный объект.

> The shuffle() method takes a sequence, like a list, and reorganize the
> order of the items.

Попробуйте:

```
import random

mylist = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
random.shuffle(mylist)

print(mylist)
```